# Oracle replace and translate command in IICS

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-cloud, informatica-powerexchange, informatica-data-integration-hub

I need to translate these oracle command into Informatica (IICS).

Please could you tell me how to do?

Regards

```sql
replace(translate(HDDJD_DG,'²¿àçéèîÀÇÉµ','           '),' ','')
```

and the last one

```sql
cast('RAP' as varchar2(3))
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [REG_REPLACE function](https://docs.informatica.com/integration-cloud/cloud-data-integration/current-version/function-reference/functions/reg_replace.html). I'm not sure if this will work simply as:

```
REG_REPLACE( HDDJD_DG, '²¿àçéèîÀÇÉµ', '')
```

or if you'd need to trim after replace:

```
LTRIM(RTRIM(REG_REPLACE( HDDJD_DG, '²¿àçéèîÀÇÉµ', '')))
```